# MySQl returns empty result in innerjoin

Tags: mysql

I am writing a simple innerjoin query but getting empty result set as return. I am not sure about the issue. Not getting the expected result.
the table structure is,

assigned......

```
    email               FacID
   aaa@aaa.com            1
   bbb@aaa.com            1
```

Learner.....

```
    email            active
  aaa@aaa.com            0
  bbb@aaa.com            1
```

I am expecting aaa@aaa.com as result, but getting empty result set. Please help.

My query is,

```
select assigned.email from assigned 
INNER JOIN learner ON assigned.email=learner.email
where  assigned.FacID=1 AND learner.active='0'
```

Comment: The query is working with both single quotes around the `0` and without it -- see this SQL fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a432d/4

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I tried but not working for me.

Comment: @bluefeet wonderign why it is not working for me. Any conditions gone wrong??

Comment: Are you really sure that the e-mailadresses are spelled the same (no white space or something like that)

Comment: @faz are you sure that the values exist in both tables? You can try to `trim()` the values in the join clause.

Comment: @bluefeet i TRIED. but still it exists.

Comment: @faz please post the table DDL and some actual sample data.  What are the datatypes of the columns?

Comment: OK. sorted out. I dropped the assigned table and created it again. Now it is working. Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the single quotes from learner.active = **'0'**